# Creating Chrome Extension - How do I populate a form

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Google Chrome extension and want to populate a form field on a page.

I am trying something like this with no effect:

```
 chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
      {code:"document.body.form[0].email_field='" + email + "'"});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You should make sure you have the "tabs" permission in your manifest.json:

> ```
> {
>   "name": "123 Testing",
>   "version": "0.1",
>   "description": ":-)",
>   "browser_action": {
>     //"default_icon": "my_icon.png",
>     "default_title": "Click to fill the form"
>   },
>   "background_page": "background.html",
>   "permissions": [
>       "tabs",
>     "http://*/"
>   ]
> }
> ```

2. I believe you should access forms with document.forms and not document.body.form.
   See my background.html file, and test it with google.com:

> ```
> <html>
>   <head>
>     <script>
>       chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
>         chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
>             code: "document.forms[0]['q'].value='Hello World!'"
>         })
>       });
>     </script>
>   </head>
>   <body></body>
> </html>
> ```

(I would have usually used document.getElementById).
Good luck!